# App42 Phonegap register user

Tags: cordova, app42

I´m using app42 to sand and receive push notifications. When I try to register use using the JS function "registerForPush" called via JAVA this message shows in LOG:

"CordovaLog(3108): : Line 1 : Uncaught ReferenceError: registerForPush is not defined"

Please help.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using App42 [Phone Gap Sample](https://github.com/VishnuGShephertz/Android-Push-Notification-in-PhoneGap-application.): it contains

- registerForPush(GCMRegId) function is written in index.html file its not the part of app42.js.
- So if you want to customize it in your own app you can use below code in Html file.

  var push = new App42Push();
      push.storeDeviceToken("Your userName",GCMRegId,'ANDROID');